# Parse.com Add Multiple Objects To One Class

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parse-platform

I have an application where I am getting data from the serial port in JSON format and I want to take this data and put it in a parse object. 
I want a new row item in the database for every new JSON object received in the serial port.

When I try to implement this, the object is created and data does get to the database, however it keeps overwriting and all I have left is one row with the latest data.

My code is as follows (note it is in Node.js with Parse npm module):

```
var Parse = require('parse').Parse;
Parse.initialize("key hidden", "key hidden");
var Parent = Parse.Object.extend("Parent");
var parent = new Parent();

var serialport = require('serialport').SerialPort;
var serialport = new serialport('COM5', {
    //parser:serialport.parsers.readline("\r\n")
    //parser:serialport.parsers.readline("\r\n"),
});
serialport.on('open', function(){
    console.log('Port is open');    
    serialport.on('data', function(data){
            //console.log('Connected to ', url);
            var data1 = JSON.parse(data);
            var testdata = {Temp:data1.Temp};
            parent.save(testdata).then(function(object) {
                console.log('inserted')
            });
    }); 
});
```

I hope someone can help me fix this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Nikhil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `var parent = new Parent();` to your `serialport.on` function, so that it is re-initialized before every save.

Right now, since `parent`is a global variable that is only initialized once, every time you save it, you're just saving the old object with new data. If you initialize the new object before you save it, then a new record will be created in the database.

Comment: Awesome! That is what is was. Thank you!